# Different output based on date in records

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I have a table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders(
    `Order` int,
    `Date` DATE,
    `Amount` int);
```

How can I get all records, but display the date of those records older than one year as blank and otherwise show the date of the records one year old or younger?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? (MySQL,Mssql,oracle)

Answer (score 1):

For MSSQL:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,[Date],GETDATE()) > 365 THEN NULL ELSE [Date] END AS [Date] FROM yourTable
```

For MySQL:

```
SELECT `Order`, (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),Date) > 365 THEN NULL ELSE Date END) AS Date, Amount FROM yourTable;
```

For Oracle:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SYSDATE - yourDateColum > 365 THEN NULL ELSE yourDateColumn END FROM yourTable
```

Comment: This is assumed that the OP is using mssql. Right?

Comment: If you want it iven cleaner follow dodexahedron's instructions but put conditions in custom function and call it in SELECT statement (passing value from column as argument).

Comment: MySQL and Oracle solutions added as well

Comment: The answer for MSSQL is wrong.  Read the documentation on `datediff()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx).

Comment: If you're talking about the column name, that's because he hadn't added the schema until I had already answered.  I'll update that in a sec.

Comment: Also, I just updated the MySQL answer, since the order of the operators was reversed.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for MySQL is:

```
select `order`,
       (case when date >= date_add(now(), interval -365 day) as date
        end),
       amount
```

By the way, it is bad practice to gives tables or columns reserved words.  `Order` is a reserved word.  Often, making it plural or something like `OrderId` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `dateadd()` as well as `getdate()` in your sql statement.

Something like this

```
select Order, case when Date <= dateadd(yy, -1, getdate()) then null else Date end as [PastYearOnly], Amount from [OrderTable]
```

As Arion mentions ... this is for MS SQL.  If you have a different database system it might be a bit different

Comment: When the intent is getting a difference between two dates, it's not as intuitive, especially when looking at a query months later, to see the DATEADD function being used.  Although this results in the same behavior, for clarity's sake, please use DATEDIFF when DATEDIFF is more appropriate.  You wouldn't say to someone "Give me the orders that are less than today plus negative one year old."  You would say "give me the orders that are less than a year old from today."

Comment: True - I had thought about datediff after I typed up the response, then saw your answer so I didn't bother updating.